# How to release the anonymous inode created by eventfd/eventpoll/timerfd?

Tags: linux, inode, google-benchmark

I am trying to measure an API using Google Benchmark. It deals with the client/server code. The Google Benchmark application, runs the setUp() TearDown() pairs several times to measure the timing in an appropriate way. The client/server works over TCP Transport.

Problem:
Within a single process (Google Benchmark) the client is restarted many number of times. This causes remnant anonymous inodes existing and as a result, I get an error

> epoll: too many files open

When I try lsof | grep "a_inode", I see that all the anonymous inodes created by eventfd/eventpoll/filefd exist in opened state.

> COMMAND       PID     TID             USER    FD       TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
>
> gbench    6514    6517         boarnerges 1020u  a_inode               0,13        0       9567 [eventfd]
>
> gbench    6514    6517         boarnerges 1021u  a_inode               0,13        0       9567 [eventpoll]
>
> gbench    6514    6517         boarnerges 1022u  a_inode               0,13        0       9567 [timerfd]
>
> gbench    6514    6520         boarnerges cwd       DIR                8,1     4096     543203 /home/boarnerges/project_GoogleBenchmark/build
>
> gbench    6514    6520         boarnerges rtd       DIR                8,1     4096          2 /
>
> gbench    6514    6520         boarnerges txt       REG                8,1  2494784     949699 /home/boarnerges/project_GoogleBenchmark/build/tests/tests/GBenchmarkTests/benchmark_client/it_gbenchmark_client

How do I solve this problem? Can the anonymous inodes be released from within the process?

Comment: Is this the full output of "lsof | grep a_inode"? 3 does not seem like a lot, or enough to exhaust process- or system-wide file descriptors. It's also not clear to me if it's your code (the one being benchmarked) that is creating these epoll FDs or if it's Google Benchmark.

Comment: I am using C++ asio library (for the client creation) and it is managing the epoll stuff. This is not the full output of the lsof command. The real output is so so huge. I have just added the last five lines (1020, 1021, 1022). The limit is 1024.

Comment: I can only guess that asio could be misused to prevent the relevant destructor from closing the epoll file descriptor (which in turn would release the associated anonymous inode). From a quick search, asio is doing this in the destructor of https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/boost/asio/detail/epoll_reactor.hpp (see "close(epoll_fd_)")